# How to dynamically combine two regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, yup

Can two regex be combined? Like it should match this regex or the other. Ideally exclusively (xor).

For instance, I want to validate a phone number against a landline phone number regex and a mobile phone number regex.

I wish I could do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
const landlinePhoneRegExp = /(^1300\d{6}$)|(^1800|1900|1902\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^13\d{4}$)|(^04\d{2,3}\d{6}$)/
const mobilePhoneRegExp = /^04[0-9 ]+/
const stripOutDelimiters = regex => etc...

const phoneRegExp = `/${stripOutDelimiters(landlinePhoneRegExp)}|${stripOutDelimiters(mobilePhoneRegExp)}/`,
```

**UPDATE**: I forgot to add that I'm using the Yup library for validation! The code looks like this:

```
const validationSchema = (t, i18n) => Yup.object.shape({
  phone: Yup.string()
    .required(t('formValidationPhoneRequired'))
    .matches(localeRegex[i18n.language].phoneRegExp, t('formValidationPhoneInvalid'))
})
```

This explains why I was trying to dynamically combine the two regex into one like in the non-working example above.

I've been looking at the [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for a while now but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. Maybe `lazy()` would be useful but apparently I can't use `string.matches()` then... unless I match `(landlineMatch || mobileMatch)` to boolean(), but how could I do that?

```
phone: Yup.lazy((value) => {
  const landlineMatch = value.match(localeRegex[i18n.language].landlinePhoneRegExp)
  const mobileMatch = value.match(localeRegex[i18n.language].mobilePhoneRegExp)

  return Yup.string()
    .required(t('formValidationPhoneRequired'))
    .matches( ??? , t('formValidationPhoneInvalid'))
})
```

Comment: Much easier if you test each individually.

Comment: The OP has specifically said they'd like to combine these dynamically, with Javascript, and with XOR logic, so I don't think either of those two answer the question.

Comment: @Andrew sure it does, how dynamic are we talking here, AI?

Comment: @ctwheels Dynamic to me implies they'd like to do this programmatically... Otherwise this question is unrelated to programming

Comment: @Andrew so the two links we provided are considered dynamic because they present a way to accomplish this programmatically, but they aren't considered dynamic to you? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Andrew: Since original 2 regex are `const` so they are not going to change for sure. Hence proposed solution is good enough.

Comment: You can combine those regexes dynamically using the answer I gave -- you just have to remove the `/` from the existing regexes and join them with `|` according to that answer. You can do that dynamically. Right?

Comment: @TKoL That works mostly but would just be OR and not XOR

Comment: Be aware that `(^1800|1900|1902\d{6}$)` matches strings that begin with `1800`  with any characters after (i.e. `1800abcg*$ù^pihybncisgf456`), or strings that have `1900` somewhere in the middle (i.e.`abcdef1900xrs654ehrbt84`) or strings that end with `1902` followed by 6 digits (i.e. `xyz1234561902123456`)

Comment: The actual problem boils down to this `^(?:(04\d{8,9})|(04[0-9 ]+))$`. The last alternation overlaps the first. In other words The first is a subset of the last. Then it does not qualify as an exclusive or XOR. All that's needed is a normal OR of the subset first.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone! The regex I used in the example look a bit funny and don't matter much. I think the XOR also doesn't matter much in my case. I came up with this which does exactly what I need: `const combineRegex = (r1, r2) => new RegExp(\`${new RegExp(r1).source}|${new RegExp(r2).source}\`)`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost done, you just need to test if they match.

To test if a string matches, just use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
landlineMatch = str.match(landlinePhoneRegExp)
mobileMatch = str.match(mobilePhoneRegExp)
```

There's no shortcut for the logical XOR test, you'll just have to use a combination of `&&` and `||` like so:

```js
(landlineMatch || mobileMatch) && !(landlineMatch && mobileMatch)
```

Comment: Or `(landlineMatch && !mobileMatch) || (mobileMatch && !landlineMatch)`

Comment: Or simply `if (!landlineMatch !== !mobileMatch)` (xor is equivalent to the two expressions evaluating to different Boolean values, one true and the other false)